# How to integrate LuaJIT with LuaRocks on Windows?

Tags: lua, luajit, luarocks

I downloaded the source of LuaJIT and compiled it with msvc120.dll (VS 2013 x64). When I run it from the command line I have no problems executing some basic lua. Now the LuaJIT installation guide mentions moving luajit.exe and lua51.dll into their own folder. From there it says to create a lua folder and under that a jit folder with the contents of src/jit moved underneath the newly created jit folder.

From my understanding my folder should look like and contain:

```
luajit.exe
lua51.dll
/lua
   /jit
       bc.lua
       [rest of jit files]
       vmdef.lua
```

Is this correct or am I missing files?

Now after I built my luajit I tried to wire it up into my luarocks to act as my interpreter using

```
install.bat /LUA C:\LuaJIT\2.0.3\[folder with above content]
```

However this cannot find the header files. I then copied over what are the header files into the folder above and that wires it up, but I can never actually get anything to compile when pointed over to LuaJIT. **Edit**: The error I get is the following,

```
C:\LuaJIT\2.0.3\bin\lua51.dll : fatal error LNK1107: invalid or corrupt file: cannot read at 0x2D0

Error: Failed installing dependency: https://rocks.moonscript.org/luafilesystem-1.6.2-2.src.rock - Build error: Failed compiling module lfs.dll
```

Is the correct way to handle this to simply point to my lua binaries and from there leverage LuaJIT to run my files or am I doing something wrong with wiring up LuaJIT and luarocks? The former seems to work for the most part, since I only ran into one library compilation issue, lua-cjson.

Comment: What do you mean when you say "I can never actually get anything to compile when pointed over to LuaJIT"? What happens exactly?

Comment: @EtanReisner I updated the question with the error message.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've run on exactly the same problem, but they've found a solution right here:

https://github.com/keplerproject/luafilesystem/issues/22

I knew that for "linking DLLs statically" there is a so-called "export" .lib file, which is passed to the linker (and not the DLL itself).

So, for example, when compiling, LuaRocks was doing this:

```
cl /nologo /MD /O2 -c -Fosrc/mime.obj -ID:/LuaJIT-2.0.4/include/ src/mime.c -DLUA_COMPAT_APIINTCASTS -DLUASOCKET_DEBUG -DNDEBUG -DLUASOCKET_API=__declspec(dllexport) -DMIME_API=__declspec(dllexport) mime.c
link -dll -def:core.def -out:mime/core.dll D:/LuaJIT-2.0.4/bin/lua51.dll src/mime.obj
```

My LuaJIT was compiled from source in `D:\LuaJIT-2.0.4\src`, but I made two folders myself: `D:\LuaJIT-2.0.4\include` with all `*.h` files copied from `src` and `D:\LuaJIT-2.0.4\bin` with `luajit.exe`, `lua51.dll`, and then later `lua51.exp` and `lua51.lib`. Still same error, but this was the right track.

### Fix

Now, check where your LuaRocks configs are:

```
luarocks.bat help
```

Scroll down to a section like:

```
CONFIGURATION
    Lua version: 5.1
    Configuration files:
            System: D:/luarocks/config-5.1.lua (ok)
            User  : (... snip ...)
```

Edit the System configuration file, specifically see the part:

```
variables = {
    MSVCRT = 'VCRUNTIME140',
    LUALIB = 'lua51.dll' 
}
```

Here! `LUALIB` should be the `.lib` file. If your export lib is alongside the DLL, you just need to change to:

```
variables = {
    MSVCRT = 'VCRUNTIME140',
    LUALIB = 'lua51.lib' -- here!
}
```

### Verification

And now:

```
luarocks.bat install luasocket
(...)
link -dll -def:core.def -out:socket/core.dll D:/LuaJIT-2.0.4/bin/lua51.lib src/luasocket.obj (...)
(...)
luasocket 3.0rc1-2 is now built and installed in D:\luarocks\systree (license: MIT)
```

Note the first argument passed to the linker.